# How to add SharePoint group in Person or Group column using JSOM

Tags: jsom, groups, person

I found many articles on how to add user in Person or Group column using JSOM, but i couldn't find any article which shows how to add SharePoint group in Person or Group column using JSOM.

Could someone help me in this!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to set Group as a field value via SharePoint JSOM API.

Lets assume `group` variable represents [`SP.Group` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245927.aspx) which has been retrieved from the server, then list item user field value for a SharePoint Group could be set like this:

```
let groupVal = new SP.FieldUserValue();
groupVal.set_lookupId(group.get_id());

listItem.set_item(userFieldName, groupVal);
listItem.update();
ctx.executeQueryAsync(() => {
     //...
}, (sender, args) => {
    //handle error
});
```

[Example](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/7b9889d55dab968f971c8c04ff5758b0)